# Why validation for password field validation not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to the web programming can you please tell me what's wrong with following code?

```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Form Validation</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function validate (form) {
   // valriable declaration
   var returnValue = true;
   var username = form.txtUserName.value;
   var password1 = form.txtPassword.value;
   var password2 = form.txtPassword2.value;
   // check for UserName length
   if (username.length < 6) {
   returnValue = false;
   alert("Your username must be at least\n6 characters long.\nPlease try again.");
   frmRegister.txtUserName.focus();
   };
   // check for password length
   if (password1.length < 6) {
   returnValue = false;
   alert("Your password must be at least\n6 characters long.\nPlease try again.");
   frmRegister.txtPassword.value = "";
   frmRegister.txtPassword2.value = "";
   frmRegister.txtPassword.focus();
   };
   // check for match of password field
   if (password1.value != password2.value) {
   returnValue = false;
   alert("Your password entries did not match.\nPlease try again.");
   frmRegister.txtPassword.value = "";
   frmRegister.txtPassword2.value = "";
   frmRegister.txtPassword.focus();
   };
   return returnValue;
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form method="post" name="frmRegister" action="register.html" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
   <div><label for="txtUsername">UserName : </label>
   <input type="text" name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" size="12" />
   </div>
   <div><label for="txtPassword">Password : </label>
   <input type="text" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" size="12" />
   </div>
   <div>
   <label for="txtPassword2">Confirm your password : </label>
   <input type="text" name="txtPassword2" id="txtPassword2" size="12" />
   </div>
   <div>
   <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
   </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: you expect us to read this ?

Comment: when you say it's not working, what is it doing, and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: You should make your code [readable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) and put here a live example.

Comment: It is checking username length and passowrd length with the equality of password.

Comment: yes, that part is clear, but what is the ERROR?

Comment: I don't have a website, how can i put it online?

Comment: it's submitting without form validations. It goes to register.html even if i leave password2 box blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all stop using return from `event handler`. 
convert your code to 

`<form ... onsubmit="validate(event,this)">`

change your function to `validate(event,form)`;

wherever you feel form should not be submitted..
write :

`event.preventDefault()`

instead of `return false`

Demonstration : 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kGmeL

Comment: Can you please show me a simple example how to do it? I'm new to javascript.Thanks

Comment: demonstration link has been added to answer.. see

Comment: Thanks, what is the event stands for here?

Comment: And Why it's not check if both password field match. Like if i give password in first password box and leave second empty, still it get submitted. How can i stop this?

Comment: `var password1 = form.txtPassword.value;
var password2 = form.txtPassword2.value;`

because you put `password1.value != password2.value`, `password1` and `password2` is string and string does not have `value` property.

`event` is event object. read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: but after removal of password1.value != password2.value to password1  != password2 , it doesn't work properly. Any solution?

Comment: Okay, so i got solution Thanks